# FFMPEG Queue input backward in time

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to combine two audio files, and delaying the second one. Here's my command

```
ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=13500s:all=1[apad]; [0:a][apad]amix=inputs=2:weights=1|1[aout]" -map [aout] combined_audio.mka
```

Here is the output that i'm getting, and it's causing an issue where the second audio is delayed by 5 hours and 45 minutes rather than 3 hours and 45 minutes

```
 ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=13500s:all=1[apad]; [0:a][apad]amix=inputs=2:weights=1|1[aout]" -map [aout] combined_audio.mka
ffmpeg version n5.0-4-g911d7f167c-20220311 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.533_681aaef)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220311
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.16.2
    creation_time   : 2022-03-23T21:20:27.000000Z
  Duration: 03:45:00.47, start: 0.291000, bitrate: 19 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.16.2
    creation_time   : 2022-03-24T01:05:30.000000Z
  Duration: 02:45:03.51, start: 13502.587000, bitrate: 5 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (opus) -> amix
  Stream #1:0 (opus) -> adelay:default
  amix:default -> Stream #0:0 (libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, matroska, to 'combined_audio.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 libvorbis
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time231x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time184x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time189x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time223x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time275x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time245x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time213x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time209x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time208x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time204x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time199x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time193x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time185x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time181x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time178x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time177x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time176x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time169x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time167x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time163x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time146x
[libvorbis @ 00000229f8a7bbc0] Queue input is backward in time139x
size=   75141kB time=06:07:52.57 bitrate=  27.9kbits/s speed= 130x
video:0kB audio:70470kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 6.628071%
```

The audio files being mixed together - https://www.easyupload.io/m/durisk

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I feel like all your timing woes are related to the fact that your containers' start times are nonzero. I haven't gripped the timestamp control in FFmpeg to a T, but see what happens if you pass all your inputs through `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` filter (one for each) before delaying or mixing.

Comment: Is this how the command should look like? ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -filter_complex "[0:a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0set]; [1:a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1set];[a1set]adelay=13500s:all=1[apad]; [a0set][apad]amix=inputs=2:weights=1|1[aout]" -map [aout] combined_audio.mka

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same issue - https://pastebin.com/DThW7gC0 . I've also uploaded the files if you want to see if you get a different result running the same command https://easyupload.io/m/durisk

Comment: You got me curious enough to dig into your files to find out what's going on. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue in these audio files appears to be the frequently dropped frames (each containing 960 audio samples). There is an instance of **8117 seconds** gap between 2 successive frames in the first file. Because the MKA files were formed without filling these dropped frames, they are effectively variable-sampling-rate streams while labeled as constant-sampling-rate. This discrepancy makes your audios to appear shorter than they were recorded, explaining why your output is often much longer than expected and has been wrecking havoc on your attempt to work on these files.

<strike>While atm I do not know if FFmpeg offers a mechanism to fix/estimate the dropped frames in these files, y</strike>You can brute-force/ignore the dropped frames by:

**amix**

```
ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka \
       -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka \
       -filter_complex "[1:a]asetpts=NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/SR/TB,adelay=13500s:all=1[apad]; \
                        [0:a]asetpts=NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/SR/TB,[apad]amix=inputs=2:weights=1|1[aout]" \
-map [aout] combined_audio.mka
```

**concat**

It appears your filtergraph really just concatenates 2 streams by delaying the second by the duration of the first. You can do the following instead:

```
ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka \
       -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka \
       -filter_complex "[1:a]asetpts=NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/SR/TB,[0a]concat=2:0:1[aout]; \
                        [0:a]asetpts=NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/SR/TB[0a]" \
       -map [aout] combined_audio.mka
```

**explanation**

`asetpts` filters are used to completely ignore what the files say about the time of the frames being fed to the filtergraph and recompute the new PTS of each frame by using the following variables and formula:

- `NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES` number of samples processed
- `SR`: sampling rate (samples/second)
- `TB`: timebase (second)
- `NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/SR/TB`: new PTS (starting TB block index)

**video streams**

If your video files have the same issue, you can likewise use the `setpts` filter:

```
setpts=N/FR/TB
```

**filling missing frames**

[`aresample`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aresample-1) can be used to fill the missing frames with zero-valued samples (silence). ([a reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847587/4516027). You can give it a try to see what happens to each mka file:

```
ffmpeg -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka \
       -af "aresample=async=1 \
       patched_audio.mka
```

Note: This will make the stream longer possibly with (low-pitched?) buzzing/beeping, making it unlistenable. But, you may need to do this to make syncing them to videos. The resampler can stretch surrounding samples, so that might be a solution for you. See [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html#Resampler-Options) for `async`, `min_comp`, `min_hard_comp`, `comp_duration`, and `max_soft_comp` options.

Comment: Holy shit. Thank you for the very thorough explanation. I am going to try this out and mark your answer as correct once i'm done testing. For the video, is it going to be setpts=NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES/FR/TB or just N/FR/TB? My next question is, should i be doing these for all the video and audio files i receive from a list. The reason for asking is because i don't know beforehand whether any of the video or audio files suffer through these dropped frames. Thanks :)

Comment: The latter. `NB_CONSUMED_SAMPLES` is reserved for audio.

Comment: So this is the output from that very first command - https://pastebin.com/UjDmbPnj. The audio in is about 4 hours and 7 seconds whereas the videos they correspond to are greater than 6 hours. So, as you suspected, brute forcing the audio won't work. Also, i got this on a10b.mka audio file - https://pastebin.com/UJgj5ZSS . [Parsed_aresample_0 @ 000002b23e36bf00] [SWR @ 000002b23e378b80] "Failed to compensate for timestamp delta of 8116.889000
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 000002b23e36bf00] [SWR @ 000002b23e378b80] Failed to compensate for timestamp delta of 5321.027667". What's this?

Comment: The first one is that ginormous gap that I mentioned in my post. Are they just warnings (did it generate output)? If so, ignore them. If it's a fatal error, try setting `max_soft_comp` option to something like 0.1.

Comment: It was a warning. I did the aresample command for both files and then combined them and now it seems like the 2nd audio plays correctly after 3 hours and 45 minutes. I will mark your answer as accepted. If i have any issues with combining them with the corresponding video files, i will comment under this threat. Thank you so much for all your help Kesh :)

Comment: Just post a new question. They don't like long comment sections (as we witnessed earlier)

Comment: is there an aresample equivalent for videos? I have the same issue where the videos have a non zero start time (just like audio files). https://easyupload.io/pub9jf . If you play this video in VLC, it will start at 00:46 seconds.

Comment: `fps` or `resample`. `setpts` to adjust timestamps

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kkMuhrUH . This turned a 20 minute video into a 12 minute one.

Comment: any hints/examples?